How to test variable for multiples classes?
I want to add a condition that tests whether a present variable is an object of any of two classes:
test if db present any of 2 classes

Example 1
if (!inherits(db, c("bioData", "character"))) {
  cat("\n\t Error:\n")
  cat("\t database must be bioData or character class \n")
  stop()
}

Example 2, works, but is it valid?
if (!class(db)[1] %in% c("bioData", "character")) {
  cat("\n\t Error:\n")
  cat("\t database must be bioData or character class \n")
  stop()
}


And rather than using cat to print error messages, use the arguments of stop. (It prepends the "Error:" automatically) stop("database must be bioData or character class")

Btw what is the advantage of cat("text") + stop() over error("text") or stop("text")?

@lotus thanks for the correction! Deleted the incorrect comment.

Just for the record, answer updated, voted to reopen.

inherits allows testing for multiple classes.
> if (!inherits(X, c('foo', 'bar'))) stop('wrong class')
> if (!inherits(Y, c('foo', 'bar'))) stop('wrong class')
Error: wrong class


Data:
> X <- structure(0, class=c(class(0), c('foo')))
> Y <- structure(0, class=c(class(0), c('baz')))

